# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SubscriberClient'

Tags: python, cloud, publish-subscribe

After running `sudo pip install google.cloud.pubsub`
I am running the following python code in ubtunu google compute engine:

`import google.cloud.pubsub_v1`

I get the following error when importing this:

> ImportError: No module named pubsub_v1 attribute 'SubscriberClient'

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Update your google-cloud-pubsub to the latest version. It should resolve the issue